# Report On Business Objects Report Destinations

Tags: sdk, business-objects

Using Business Objects 4.3 I would like to create a lust of all destinations where each individual report is going. Can you point me in the right direction.

I've tried Query Builder, with little succes. However the format of results isn't easy to read.
I've looked at tge audit universe. Once again with little success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this utility which is free to download

https://bobj-board.org/t/all-scheduler-list/175779